# algorythm to find "next neighbor matching" in a multi branch tree

Tags: python, search, tree

I have a data structure that essentially is a tree with multiple branching.
The program is implemented in python (3.5, currently, if it matters).

Problem:
Starting from an arbitrary node find a "matching" node which is at the shortest possible distance.

Definition of "distance" is having the least possible number of "backtracking" (a backtrack happens when reaching back to parent from the starting node).

This means children of start node are preferred, then come children of parent of starting node, third choice are children of parent of parent of starting node, etc.

Naive implementation leads to infinite recursion:

```
    def find(self, name, skip=None):
        if self.name == name:
            return self
        for c in self.child:
            if c != skip:
                s = c.find(name, skip)
                if s is not None:
                    return s
        if name != 'Start':
            if self.parnt is not None:
                return self.parnt.find(name, self)
        return None
```

I have not found an algorithm not needing branch tagging, which is cumbersome.

Current implementation has also the problem it implements a depth-first search, while a breadth-first would be preferred.

Can someone suggest an efficient algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way of doing this with the following code:

```
def find(self, name, tovisit=None, visited=None):
    if tovisit is None:
        tovisit = []
    if visited is None:
        visited = []
    tovisit.append(self)
    while tovisit:
        s = tovisit.pop()
        visited.append(s)
        if s.name == name:
            return s
        for c in s.child:
            if c not in visited:
                tovisit.append(c)
        if name != 'Start':
            if s.parnt is not None and s.parnt not in visited:
                tovisit.append(s.parnt)
    return None
```

This iterative solution relies on two lists to handle breadth-first and avoid re-visiting nodes.

I will not accept my own answer for a while in hope a better solution may be proposed.